# What is the command to find script of a existing function in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

As we are using sp_helptext [procedure name] to get the SP script in Sqlserver, I need the command that i can use to retrieve a function script from postgresql.

Please help....

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16632213/59087

Answer (score 9):

If you are using psql (the commandline interface) you can use `\df+` as tobixen has already stated (and which is clearly documented in the manual).

If you need to do this from within a SQL query, take a look a the [system information functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE). You are looking for `pg_get_functiondef()`

```
select pg_get_functiondef(oid)
from pg_proc
where proname = 'your_function';
```

If you are dealing with overloaded functions having a different number of parameters, you need to include the parameter signature into the name:

```
select pg_get_functiondef('public.foo(int)'::regprocedure);
select pg_get_functiondef('public.foo(int,int)'::regprocedure);
```

will retrieve the overloaded versions of the function `foo` (one version with a single int parameter, the other version with two int parameters).

Answer (score 4):

At the psql command line it's `\df+ foo`, isn't it?

Other than that, `select prosrc from pg_proc where proname='foo';`