# Get all procedural , user defined functions

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

How to get list of all user defined functions via `SQL` query ?

---

I find this code [here](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/v04020a03b3f1ba2889de@%5B128.40.242.190%5D)

```
SELECT p.proname, p.pronargs, t.typname
 FROM pg_proc p, pg_language l, pg_type t
 WHERE p.prolang = l.oid
 and p.prorettype = t.oid
 and l.lanname = 'c'
ORDER BY proname;
```

but this gets C-functions

How to get user defined, procedural language functions, writen for example in `plpgsql`  language?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Consider:

```
select 
    pp.proname,
    pl.lanname,
    pn.nspname,
    pg_get_functiondef(pp.oid)
from pg_proc pp
inner join pg_namespace pn on (pp.pronamespace = pn.oid)
inner join pg_language pl on (pp.prolang = pl.oid)
where pl.lanname NOT IN ('c','internal') 
  and pn.nspname NOT LIKE 'pg_%'
  and pn.nspname <> 'information_schema';
```

See also: [What is the command to find script of a existing function in postgresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11305474/398670)

Use `pg_get_functiondef` or the `prosrc` column from `pg_proc` directly. The key idea is to join on `pg_namespace` and filter out the PostgreSQL catalog functions, which will probably be adequate for most purposes:

```
FROM pg_proc pp INNER JOIN pg_namespace ON (pp.pronamespace = pn.oid)
WHERE pn.nspname <> 'pg_catalog'
```

The trouble with obtaining the source code for *user defined* functions is deciding what *user* means. Many types of functions can be created:

- Functions using `CREATE EXTENSION`.
- Functions created by PostgreSQL.
- Functions compiled and installed by an administrator.

Superusers with sufficent grants can define functions in `pg_proc`, but usually don't.

Since only superusers can create C language functions, exclude them. Such functions can be custom-installed on a particular database by the admin, but not a normal user.

Comment: Thank you, using this query `SELECT proname,pg_get_functiondef(oid) FROM pg_proc ` we get all functions name (and definition code) right? and how get only functions, which is create from user, there is some condition  in `where` clause for this?

Comment: @OTARIKI If I understand you correctly you want only *user defined* functions. The trouble there is deciding what "user" means. Are functions added by CREATE EXTENSION user defined? What I'd suggest doing is `FROM pg_proc pp INNER JOIN pg_namespace ON (pp.pronamespace = pn.oid)` then filtering on `WHERE pn.nspname <> 'pg_catalog'` to exclude functions defined in `pg_catalog`. Users *can* define functions in `pg_proc` (if they're superuser or `GRANT`ed the rights to) but usually don't.

Comment: @ CraigRinger, ErwinBrandstetter - Thanks very much